Thumbnail/Image column broke after disabling attachments
I am currently experiencing an issue with a SharePoint list that contains a thumbnail column. After disabling the attachments for this list, I found that I could no longer access the images in the thumbnail column.
When attempting to do so, I receive the following error message:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "Attachment not found."
  }
}

This issue does not seem to affect new images that are added to the list; these work perfectly fine. However, I have tried re-enabling the attachments column to resolve the issue, but unfortunately, this has not been successful.
is there a way to solve this?

When you disable the attachments for SharePoint list, it shows message like: Disabling attachments and saving this settings page will result in the deletion of all attachments. Are you sure you want to disable attachments?. So, I think you are facing issue with thumbnail column because all previous attachments are deleted from the list.

After disabling attachments, new images are working fine because those will be saved in "Site Assets" folder if attachments are disabled. Check this for more information: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/

When you disable attachments option from SharePoint lists, it deletes all existing list item attachments.
It shows the confirmation like this while disabling attachments:


Also, new images are working fine even after disabling attachments option, because those new images will be saved in Site Assets folder when attachments are disabled.
Check this for more information: SharePoint Online: All you need to know about New Image column type

Related Read: Turning off list attachments deletes all existing attachments--Can I recover any of these files?
